# need a solution for viewing rtsp or rtmp on android?

Tags: android, stream, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

im looking for an open source/library for viewing rtsp or rtmp for android.

I have checked and tried most of the commercial libraries. 
They are unreliable,i have used vitamio and it crashes on various ocasions.

My problem is when a pc is broadcasting rtsp using h.264 and acc to a WOWZA server , i want to view the rtsp/rtmp feed without latency or delay.

The media player has at least 6 seconds delay so its out of the question. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As an option - try to search wowza support forum

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?18368-High-latency-when-streaming-live-video-rtmp
maybe the reason of 6 sec latency is in Wowza internals/configuration, not in codecs or your RTMP client.